# Order By Using Index Slow For Only Some Data

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

One org that has 30k items and takes forever for this simple query to run (doesn't finish, I have to stop it). A separate org that has 60k items returns very quickly (400 msec). Why is this happening? Do I need to rebuild index?

This is my query:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items 
WHERE items.org_id = '123-456-abc'
ORDER BY items.name ASC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` output for the org with 30k items:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..3734.80 rows=10 width=307)
  ->  Index Scan using index_items_on_name on items  (cost=0.56..11272191.50 rows=30186 width=307)
        Filter: (org_id = '123-456-abc'::uuid)
```

For the 60k items org:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..1831.41 rows=10 width=307)
  ->  Index Scan using index_items_on_name on items  (cost=0.56..11272191.50 rows=61568 width=307)
        Filter: (org_id = '789-123-def'::uuid)
```

There are 20 columns on this `items` table, and I have a non-unique index on the `name` column called `index_items_on_name` (definition says btree, sort order ASC, and NULLs LAST). I also have a trigram index on barcode, sku, and name, but it's probably not relevant because the `EXPLAIN` says it's using `index_items_on_name`.

Comment: Note the lack of a sort step. What's happening is it's scanning the index of names (which is in name order) until it sees 10 rows with a matching `org_id`. If the matching rows are named `Aardvark and Associates` it will find 10 quickly. If they are named `Zebras of Zanzibar` it will have to scan almost the whole table to find 10. The cost is an approximation based on statistics, try [analyzing the table](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html) and/or adding an index on `org_id`.

Comment: I ran `ANALYZE VERBOSE "items"`, and it came back saying `"items": scanned 30000 of 214096 pages, containing 628799 live rows and 45040 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 4487445 estimated total rows`. Ran my two queries again, and they behave the same. There already is an index on `org_id`. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schwern is correct as for why it is slow.  To make it faster, add an index on `(org_id, name)`.  That way it can use one index to do both things, find just the org requested, then read them already in order.